# How to add Cordova app to browser list in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I would like to register my app so that Android recognizes it as a browser and so that users when seeing "Open with" for http links, can choose my application.

Is there any plugin or configuration to perform in the configurations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question and I hope this might help someone else looking for this.
You can refer to [Custom URL Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)  which works pretty well, you just need to set the scheme to "https" for your application to receive https calls.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=https
```

Now, if you want it to also accept https and maybe add other schemes, you need to edit your AndroidManifest file and add intends:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Thank you.